# Ember Nested Data in JSON Response

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having some trouble accessing some nested data in one of my Ember models. Below is the JSON response...

```
{
  "fields": {
    "header": {
      "name": "header",
      "type": "text",
      "localize": false,
      "options": []
    },
    "body": {
      "name": "body",
      "type": "textarea",
      "localize": false,
      "options": []
    }
  },
  "entries": [
    {
      "header": "header test",
      "body": "body test body test body test",
      "_mby": "5a395e8430c2ddoc683600766",
      "_by": "5a395e8430c2ddoc683600766",
      "_modified": 1513709605,
      "_created": 1513709605,
      "_id": "5a3960253d578doc735798511"
    }
  ],
  "total": 1
}
```

Here is my current serializer

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) 
  {
    payload = {
      entries: payload.entries
    };
    return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
  }
});
```

I'm trying to get the Entries in my template. Perhaps I need some help better serializing this with NormalizeResponse? I'm very stumped so please share if you have any ideas!

Thanks!!

Comment: "I'm trying to get the Entries in my template." How? What is it that you are actually having trouble with?

Comment: We’ll I’ve tried many different ways. What I thought should have worked, entries: DS.attr(); , in the model does not. I’m not able to even get past the model right now..

Comment: Wait, what? From the above code I thought `entry` _is_ your model, not an attribute of some other model. (It's the only thing with an id, after all, and the serializer looks as if you're trying to remove anything that isn't `entries` from the payload.) Also, you do not show your model nor your template. It is unclear where you expect something to happen, what you expect to happen and what you observe instead.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, my model would look something like this, but I'm not able to get it to work. I think I got hung up on the serializer, and I'm not even sure if I need one..

    `import DS from 'ember-data';


    export default DS.Model.extend({
       entries: DS.attr()
    });`

In my template, I'd assume that I could loop over entries, no such luck.

```{{#each entries as |entry|}}``` etc etc

Answer (score 0):

The ember-data `RESTAdapter` expects the JSON to contain keys that correspond to model names and values to be arrays of JSON objects with key-value pairs according to the respective models' attribute-name--attribute-value-type definitions*.

So if you have a model named `entry` containing `header: attr('string'), body: attr('string')`, the following JSON should lead to an `entry` in the store:

```
{
  "entries": [{
      "header": "header test",
      "body": "body test body test body test",
      "id": "5a3960253d578doc735798511"
   }],
}
```

<sup>There is a way to convince ember-data to customize the id field name (to accept `_id` instead of `id`). The build-in pluralization rules should include the entry->entries pluralization (but I cannot vouch for it).</sup>

Any top-level key that does not correspond to a model name should be ignored anyway, so no need to filter it out manually (unless you have models named `field` or `total`).

If you then `return this.store.findAll('entry')` (or `query('entry',{/*something*/}`) in your route's model hook, you should be able to look over `{{#each model as |entry|}}` in your controller's template. 
<sub>(It is good practice to not use `model` as the model name, but if you want it to be `entries`, you have to specify that explicitly somewhere, i.e. the controller or the route's `setupController` method.)</sub>

*The point of repeating the name of the model as top-level key in the json response (presumably to an API endpoint of the same name) is that you can include other models if you whish and they will be added to the store as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help arne.b. I'll try this now!